# Links not opening with left click

Tags: hyperlink

I am having a bit of a problem with my site, i am trying to add a simple link to an external site, but i can't get the link to open without right clicking and selecting open link.

This is the piece of code

```
<div class="brick1 odd">
                <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/" class="nav-item"</a>
                    <div class="nav-hover"></div>
                    <i class="li_shop"></i>
                    <span>Shop now</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

I know it's most likely something simple but i can't seem to pin it down

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!  The problem is because you are trying to link from an http to an https!

Your anchor tag needs to override the click handler:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/" class="nav-item" onclick="return !window.open(this.href,'WINDOW_NAME');" >
```

Should fix it!

But I would still fix the nesting.

try properly nesting everything, like so:

```
<div class="brick1 odd">
    <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/" class="nav-item" onclick="return !window.open(this.href,'WINDOW_NAME');">
       <div class="nav-hover">
           <i class="li_shop">
                <span>Shop now</span>
           </i>
       </div>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hey eidsonator, thanks but i have tried changing the tags without any success.  Cheers

Comment: @user2339515 See my newest edit... it was a problem going from an http location to a https location

Comment: Thanks again, changing as per the edit still results in not working link, but it also messes up the icons and text. link 1 is the page as i have done it, link 2 with your edit http://tester.atwebpages.com/live_menu.html http://tester.atwebpages.com/live_menu1.html                   Thanks again for the help

Comment: @user2339515 did you see the onclick handler change?  That'll fix it, and you should be able to move the nesting back to how you had it!

Comment: Thats done it, thank you very much your a star, had me scratching my head all day :)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/" class="nav-item">
                    <div class="nav-hover"></div>
                    <i class="li_shop"></i>
                    <span>Shop now</span>
                </a>
```